# Table scraped from a web page is read as a single character vector: how to convert into a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, rvest

I have scraped a large table from a web page using the rvest package, but it is reading it as a single vector:

```
foo<-c("A","B","C","Dog","1","2","3","Cat","4","5","6","Goat","7","8","9")
```

that I need to deal with as a dataframe that looks like this:

```
bar<-as.data.frame(cbind(Animal=c("Dog","Cat","Goat"),A=c(1,4,7),B=c(2,5,8),C=c(3,6,9)))
```

This might be a simple dilemma but I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: You don't have "Animal" in foo?

Comment: No, in the data that is scraped, the "animal" column label is implied.

Comment: While the options below are certainly workable, the alternative is to just scrape to a better structure in the first place.

Comment: having the URL or actual HTML excerpt would be great, unless you're stealing content from ToS a prohibited site or it's sensitive data. For the latter (I won't help theft in the former) you can make it a minimum reproducible HTML excerpt and change the values. It's likely that a jsonlite param change or a modified scraping idiom wld get you what you need.

Comment: That would be great. This is my first effort scraping and would love to get it right.

Not sensitive data: this is what I'm doing.

library(rvest)
  url<-read_html("http://apps.who.int/immunization_monitoring/globalsummary/timeseries/tswucoveragemcv1.html")

  selector_table<-".borderonBBleft .GSCPdataTitle , .borderonBBright"
  fdata<-html_nodes(x = url, css = selector_table) %>%
  html_text()

  fdata<-c("Country",fdata)

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. Might be easier to open a new question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a matrix from your vector and turn it into a data frame:

```
foo<-c("A","B","C","Dog","1","2","3","Cat","4","5","6","Goat","7","8","9")
foo <- c("Animal" , foo)
m <- matrix(foo , ncol = 4  , byrow = TRUE)
df <- as.data.frame(m[-1,] , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  
colnames(df) <- m[1,]
# I assume you want numerics for your A,B,C columns:
df[,2:4]<-apply(df[,2:4],2,as.numeric)

lapply(df,class)
$Animal
[1] "character"

$A
[1] "numeric"

$B
[1] "numeric"

$C
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick nicely. As suggested by alistair and hrbrmstr above, I need to figure out how to scrape the data better, but this will do the trick for now.

Answer (score 2):

Just `split` it into required number of rows and `rbind` it. I added `"Animal"` at the start of `foo` to make the elements equal in each row when splitting

```
foo = c("Animal", foo)
df = data.frame(do.call(rbind, split(foo, ceiling(seq_along(foo)/4))),
                                                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(df) = df[1,]
df = df[-1,]
df
#  Animal A B C
#2    Dog 1 2 3
#3    Cat 4 5 6
#4   Goat 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the proper column types, you can try this.  Split into a list, name the list, then convert the column types before coercing to data frame.

```
l <- setNames(split(tail(foo, -3), rep(1:4, 3)), c("Animal", foo[1:3]))
as.data.frame(lapply(l, type.convert))  ## stringsAsFactors=FALSE if desired
#    Animal A B C
# 1     Dog 1 2 3
# 2     Cat 4 5 6
# 3    Goat 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a convenient tool to work with list,

```
 seqList <-
function(character,by= 1,res=list()){
    ### sequence characters by 
    if (length(character)==0){
        res
    } else{
        seqList(character[-c(1:by)],by=by,res=c(res,list(character[1:by])))

    }
    }
```

Once you convert your characters into lists it's easier to manipulate them for instance you can do.

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

foo <-c("A","B","C","Dog","1","2","3","Cat","4","5","6","Goat","7","8","9")
foo <- c("Animal",foo)

df <- data.frame(t(do.call("rbind",
    lapply(1:4,function(x) do.call("cbind",lapply(seqList(foo,4),"[[",x))))))

colnames(df) <- df[1,]

df <- df[-1,]

## > df
##   Animal A B C
## 2    Dog 1 2 3
## 3    Cat 4 5 6
## 4   Goat 7 8 9
```

**Note**:
I haven't tested the efficiency of the function. It might not be very efficient for large amount of characters.
The use of matrices might a better tool for this job.